# How do I get user details in Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-storage

I'm a new programmer and very new to firebase and I'm trying to get the current user files info to display on the screen, it seems that my problem is that I can get the URL and the metadata separately, how do I combine them? how can I take everything at once?
I need to show the file name, date, time, link to download.

```js
const getUserFiles = async () => {
  if (!userUID) {
    return null;
  }
  let listRef = storageRef.child(userUID);
  listRef.listAll().then(res => {
    // res.prefixes.forEach((item) => {
    // });
    res.items.forEach(item => {
      item.getMetadata().then(item => {
        var file = {
          name: item.name.toString(),
          timeCreated: item.timeCreated.toString(),
          link: '',
        };
        myFiles.push(file);
      });
    });
    res.items.forEach(item => {
      let counter = 0;
      item.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        myFiles[counter].link = url.toString();
      });
    });
  });
  console.log(myFiles);
};
```

the current method don't work! and notice that the userUID its only the uid without the user (local state)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the asynchronous calls. You're making an async call in `forEach` and [forEach expects a synchronous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20forEach%20expects%20a%20synchronous%20function.).

You can change the logic to use [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead.

See below:

```js
const getUserFiles = async () => {
  if (!userUID) {
    return null;
  }

  let listRef = storageRef.child(userUID);

  const res = await listRef.listAll();

  for (const itemRef of res.items) {
    const itemMetadata = await itemRef.getMetadata();
    const url = await itemRef.getDownloadUrl();

    var file = {
      name: itemMetadata.name.toString(),
      timeCreated: itemMetadata.timeCreated.toString(),
      link: url,
    };

    myFiles.push(file);
  }

  console.log(myFiles);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!
when I've copied it I've got this error:
  Line 24:14:  'itemRef' is not defined  no-undef      
  Line 25:38:  'itemRef' is not defined  no-undef      
  Line 26:29:  'itemRef' is not defined  no-undef 

and I cant understand why. it supposed to iterate on the res.items

Comment: I've updated the code. There should be `const` before `itemRef` in the `for` loop